# The pigeonhole principle - how to solve questions like that?

Tags: summation, pigeonhole-principle

We have two sequences , $(a_i)_{i=1}^{2n}$ and $(b_i)_{i=1}^{2n}$ such that 
$1\leq a_i, b_i\leq n$ for every $i$.

Show that there are two sets of indexes $I, J \subseteq \left \{ 1,2, ... 2n \right \}$ such what $\sum_{i\in I}a_i=\sum_{j\in J}b_j$.

Well, the question didn't say anything about those sets being empty but I believe that's not what they meant. I don't know that to do with questions like these.
There are obviously much more subsets that possible sums ($2^{2n}-1$ compared to $2n^2$) but it doesn't really help.

I'd be glad to hear ideas, hints or solutions.

Comment: I think it is possible to show with induction on the length $n$. you will have to show that with $2n$ elements of ${1..n}$ you can reach sum of $(n+1)k$ where $k$ is anything between $1$ and 2$n$

Comment: What does mean exactly the notation in "a sequence of $(a_i)_{i=1}^{2n}$ " ?

Comment: What kind of numbers are $a_i$ and $b_i$?

Comment: " There are obviously much more subsets that possible sums (22n−1 compared to 2n2) but it doesn't really help."  On the contarty! That is *exactly* why the statement must be true.  If there are more subsets then sums, two subsets must have the same sum as then can't all have different sums.

Comment: can you please answer the questions raised in the comments please? where did you get this question from? is this the complete question?

Comment: All the numbers are integers. This is a question from a test I had and it is the complete question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that $a_i$ and $b_i$ denote integers, although that is not stated in the OP.

Define $S_j = \sum_{i=1}^j a_i$ and $T_k = \sum_{i=1}^k b_i$, so $1 \leq S_j \leq 2n^2$ and $1 \leq T_k \leq 2n^2$ for $1 \leq j \leq 2n$ and $1 \leq k \leq 2n$.  Notice that the $S_j$'s are all distinct, and so are the $T_k$'s. We have $|S_j - T_k| \leq 2n^2-1$, so there are $4n^2-1$ possible values of $S_j-T_k$ for $1 \leq j \leq 2n$ and $1 \leq k \leq 2n$.

Consider the $4n^2$ pairs $(S_j, T_k)$ for $1 \leq j \leq 2n$ and $1 \leq k \leq 2n$.  Since there are more pairs than there are possible values of $S_j-T_k$, by the pigeonhole principle there must be at least two distinct pairs, say $(S_j,T_k)$ and $(S_l, T_m)$, which map to the same difference, i.e.
$$S_j- T_k = S_l - T_m$$  We may as well assume, without loss of generality, that $j > l$.  Then
$$S_j - S_l = T_k - T_m$$
implies
$$\sum_{i=l+1}^j a_i = \sum_{i=m+1}^k b_i$$