# Equality of sums of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, summation

> We have two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, of positive integers, such that, $1\leq a_1,...,a_m\leq n$, $1\leq b_1,...,b_n\leq m$ prove that there exist $p\leq q$, $r\leq s$ such that,
>
> $$\sum_{i=p}^{q} a_i =\sum_{i=r}^{s}b_i$$

I think Pigeon Hole Principle can be applied, but I'm not sure how.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are these sequences of integers?

Comment: This is absolutely not true without further conditions. Perhaps the $a_n$ and $b_n$ must be integers? In which case the pigeonhole principle might be brought to bear.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Added details.

Comment: @Henry: Why do say "it seems trivial"?

Comment: If $n=1$,
then all $a_i = 1$
and $1 \le b_1 \le m$.
This then says that
$q-p+1 =b_1$.
Which is true.

This might form the base case for an induction proof.

Comment: A similar (but not identical) question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870377/the-pigeonhole-principle-how-to-solve-questions-like-that

Comment: @awkward Good catch! In fact, the *solution* to the question you point to solves this one, too. So I'll vote to close this one, now.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Although the questions are quite similar, this one is a generalization of the previous result (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870377/the-pigeonhole-principle-how-to-solve-questions-like-that)).  The previous question is the case $m=n$, whereas in this question we do not have that restriction.  It shouldn't be difficult to apply the same method of proof, however (I think).